# Python Visualize K-clustering

Tags: python, nltk, k-means

I have follow this tutorial http://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/k-means-clustering-example-word2vec/ for the K-clustering using NLTK package part.

```
The code for NLTK K-clustering is like this :
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
Cluster = 2
Kcluster = KMeansClusterer(Cluster,distance = nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance,repeats = 25 )
ApplyCluster = Kcluster.cluster(model[abc.vocab], assign_clusters=True)
```

So for this i want to visualize our result, but i have no idea. I have try plot.scatter() but i have some problems to define which parameter to take.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. Try various combinations of 2 dimensions.
2. Use `PCA` to transform the data, and pick the first 2 principal components.
3. [t-sne](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) is a great dimension reduction technique for visualizations.

**EDIT**: You may look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mini_batch_kmeans.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-mini-batch-kmeans-py) for plotting ideas (technical, not mathematical)
**EDIT 2**: As mentioned by @Dan, [t-sne](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) is a great dimension reduction technique for visualizations, based on similarity matrices and the modified algorithm (hence **t**-sne) does that very good.

Good luck!

Comment: For visualisation, [tsne](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) is probably better than PCA

Comment: Thanks @Dan , true, I just followed his example and question - how to choose the attribute.